# Getting the ID of a Model that Uses Nested Routes and Permalinks in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-routes

So I had my app set up with ids like so:

```
  resources :studios do
     resources :bookings
  end
```

This gave me the route to the index (which later I'm going to use json for to get calendars for each studio.

```
 studio_bookings GET    /studios/:studio_id/bookings(.:format)          bookings#index
```

This is good, but I wanted to get rid of the ID and use a permalink instead, just for a friendlier URL.

Change to:

```
  namespace :studio, :path =>'/:permalink' do
     resources :bookings
  end
```

Now I'm getting

```
studio_bookings GET   /:permalink/bookings(.:format)      studio/bookings#index
```

Great! this is how I want my url to look, however, now the :id isn't anywhere in the route so... I get

```
Couldn't find Booking without an ID
```

It isn't even being passed.  Is there a way to pass the :id in with the url without it being actually USED in the url?  Otherwise, do I change the primary key from :id to :permalink in order to fix this?

I tried changing my controller from

```
    @studio = Studio.find(params[:id])
```

to

```
    @studio = Studio.find(params[:permalink])
```

but that gives me

```
Couldn't find Booking with 'id'=40frost
```

Which tells me what I'm doing isn't really meant to be done? It's trying to put the permalink as the id, so even though I'm telling rails to look for the permalink, it's still seemingly looking it up as an ID.

Hopefully my problem is clear: essentially - how can I pass the id so it knows which studio without displaying it in the URL.  If there's some controller magic I can do instead that would be convenient.

Here's my controller for good measure

```
class Studio::BookingsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_booking, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /bookings
  # GET /bookings.json
  def index
    @studio = Studio.find(params[:permalink])
    @bookings = Booking.where("studio_id => '@studio.id'")
  end

  # GET /bookings/1
  # GET /bookings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /bookings/new
  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
  end

  # GET /bookings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /bookings
  # POST /bookings.json
  def create
    @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @booking.save
        format.html { redirect_to @booking, notice: 'Booking was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @booking }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /bookings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /bookings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @booking.update(booking_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @booking, notice: 'Booking was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /bookings/1
  # DELETE /bookings/1.json
  def destroy
    @booking.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to bookings_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_booking
      @booking = Booking.find(params[:permalink])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def booking_params
      params.require(:booking).permit(:start_time, :end_time, :studio_id, :engineer_id, :title, :allDay)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do

```
self.primary_key = 'permalink'
```

in your Studio model, or you could do

```
def index
  @studio = Studio.find_by permalink: params[:permalink]
  @bookings = Booking.where(studio_id: @studio.id)
end
```

depends if you just want to locally change the behavior or adress the Studio model by permalink always.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you.  I went with the second method.

Comment: That is probably prudent because you will want to use your IDs for retrieving records for updating and stuff, good luck out there!